# What's a good practice to construct a feature vector based on formulas?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, feature-extraction, feature-selection

I am newbie to data mining, and currently I am thinking to construct feature vector based on a set of formulas.

In particular, I have a number of data, each data is a formula, something like this:

```
Y = (x1 * 5) >> 4 + (x2 * 6)
```

Note that formulas are not very large.

I basically want to extract a feature vector on the basis of each formula, and undertakes a classic k-mean clustering algorithm.

However, I am trapped to generate a good feature vector from formulas.

I can of course start from this :

```
(N_number_of_variable, N_number_of_const, N_number_of_operator)
```

But note that each formula is actually quite small, and actually I have many one variable formula, like this:

```
Y1 = X2
Y2 = X3
....
```

So I guess the naive approach above might not be a good way to go.

As I basically don't have experience on data mining project before, I am trying to ask whether there is a good way to build feature vector given my situation.?

Am I clear? thank you!

Dear all, I attached more data samples here:

```
reg8 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 - 12

reg8 - 44

reg8

reg8 + 44

reg8 - 4 - 4 - 20

reg8

reg8 + 24 + 4

reg8

reg8 + 60 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4

reg8

reg8
```

What I want to do:

Actually each symbolic formula above represents the semantic information of a CPU register when it is executing some CPU instructions.

I want to identify a sequence of **specific** CPU instruction, by looking at (clustering) its corresponding symbolic formula.

For example:

If after clustering, symbolic formulas below have been clustered into one category:

```
reg8 + 60 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 
reg8 + 24 + 4
reg8 + 44
```

Then I will take a look at the ground truth, and check whether the corresponding instruction sequences are surely the specific instructions sequence I am looking for.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. I don't think k-means will ever work on such data (it needs *continuous* values, so counting anything does not help), so extracting features is pointless...

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, hello, I updated my question. Could you take a look and give me some help..? thank you a lot!

Comment: I do not at all understand how you arrive to the last example. And how this relates to clustering. Sure you aren't looking for e.g. frequent itemsets?